# How to loop part of an animation in Unity

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

What is the best solution to **loop only a part of an animation** in Unity ?

The best I can find is [Animation CrossFade](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.CrossFade.html) , so if I have a 3 min animation and I want to loop only during 0:30 and 1:00, *the code is* :

```
void Start() {
        anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
}
void Foo() {
        anim["Take_01"].time = 30.0;
        anim.CrossFade("Take_01",30.0, PlayMode.StopSameLayer);
}
```

Comment: Did you consider splitting the animation, to separate the part you want to loop from the rest, and trigger other parts when you need them ?

Comment: I also consider that but, I want to know if therefore there's a solution without doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this solution is adapted to what you want to do as I never experienced it myself, but it seems that there is something called [Animation Clips](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimationClip.html) that you can use to [loop in an animation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoopingAnimationClips.html), which seems to be neat, as it's capable of detecting the animated element's position to see if there would be flickering when looping back to the beginning.